# Second button not working, but the first does

Tags: android, button, android-intent, android-activity

I created a main.xml where I had 4 buttons, then, I created Activity, where I wrote an Intent for the first button to open a new activity and it worked. But then, I wanted to do the same for the second button, but it didn't do the same like the first one.. and my answer is why? Why should I change to do the same action?

Here is the codes..

main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/noua" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/zece" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/unspe" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/doispe" />


</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.orar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

    //implement the OnClickListener interface
    public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements OnClickListener {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //get the Button reference
            //Button is a subclass of View 
            //buttonClick if from main.xml "@+id/buttonClick"
            View btnClick = findViewById(R.id.button1);
            //set event listener
            btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        //override the OnClickListener interface method
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            if(arg0.getId() == R.id.button1){
                //define a new Intent for the second Activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
                //start the second Activity
                this.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
```

From here starts the second button and the problem...

```
        //implement the OnClickListener interface
        public class MainActivity  extends Activity
        implements OnClickListener {
            /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                //get the Button reference
                //Button is a subclass of View 
                //buttonClick if from main.xml "@+id/buttonClick"
                View btnClick = findViewById(R.id.button2);
                //set event listener
                btnClick.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            //override the OnClickListener interface method
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if(arg0.getId() == R.id.button2){
                    //define a new Intent for the second Activity
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
                    //start the second Activity
                    this.startActivity(intent2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

SecondActivity.java:

```
package com.orar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.second);

    }
}
```

ThirdActivity.java:

```
package com.orar;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ThirdActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.third);

    }
}
```

second.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="This is the second Activity"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

third.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:text="This is the third Activity"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: There is no call of second button in your activity. May you share what you've tried and tell us exactly what does not work as expected ?

Comment: How should i call my second button in my activity?  I tried to change things in to make the second button start a new activity, but i didn't .. What should I change in the first button's codes to make the same action for the second button?

Answer (score 2):

You have many problems. First, you set a click listener only for you first button :

```
//buttonClick if from main.xml "@+id/buttonClick"
View btnClick = findViewById(R.id.button1);
//set event listener
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
```

You should do it for your four buttons :

```
findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button2).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(this);
findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then, second problem is on your onClick method, you performs actions only if button one is clicked. You should perform actions if one of the four buttons is clicked :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // create a general intent
    Intent intent = null;
    // define an intent for all cases
    switch(arg0.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            // Setting intent for first button
            intent = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            // Setting intent for second button
            intent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            // Setting intent for third button
            intent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            // Setting intent for fourth button
            intent = new Intent(this,ThirdActivity.class);
            break;
    }
    // start the Activity selected at the end
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: But after creating this cases, what do I have to do for every case to open another Activity not the same?

Comment: You change the text that is within the cases for each of the buttons in the onClick method. So if you want to have a different activity start when clicking on button 3 you write a new intent under `case R.id.button3: Intent intent = ...; break;`

Comment: pay attention gahfy.
You redeclared Intent intent in every case. Use the one you declared on top of onCLick method or program will crush for NullPointerException

Comment: Yes you were right Tommaso Resti Thanks to you and Fllo (who edited my code). Wrong copy/paste from me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Precisely what you can do is create a method named `onButtonPressed()` in your main activity. It will handle our button press events.

```
public void onButtonPressed(View v) {
    Intent startActivityIntent = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button1:
            startActivityIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        break;

        case R.id.button2:
            startActivityIntent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
        break;

        case R.id.button3:
        break;

        case R.id.button4:
        break;
    }
    if(startActivityIntent != null)
    startActivity(startActivityIntent);
}
```

Now add the `onClick` attribute of button in the main.xml as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:onClick="onButtonPressed" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/noua"
    android:onClick="onButtonPressed" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/zece" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/unspe"
    android:onClick="onButtonPressed" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/doispe"
    android:onClick="onButtonPressed" />
```